# Fake Url(temp hold from http response) for http request in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I need to hold a JSON response which comes from HTTP request to further use that JSON response as a URL to get another HTTP request.

suppose I have http://xyzorig.com/api.
then I receive JSON data.
What I want is that, I need to pass the new JSON data:
suppose:
 var Obj = That JSON data

to another http request, Which can be fake.
Like http://fakeusingJSONData.com/anyfake
Which gives same response obviously.

I know Its to hard to understand but I have a code which need jsonp request but Jsonp doesn't comes with http header so , For doing that I will do that.

Comment: What is question?

Comment: Do it as you explained, and if you got an issue, then post the code and be more clear to get a help. Best of luck

Comment: You are looking for switchMap

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick ,
I am working on the following code :- https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/external-editing/ .
There , They are using jsonp to get response from server but in my api , I need to send header along with it to get response from server , Which I am unable to do.

Comment: @MaihanNijat , So If I get the data using http.get then use that JSON in fake api using call in jsonp , so I think I will achieve , my desired result.

Comment: @Eliseo, I dont know, I am working on the following code :- telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/… . There , They are using jsonp to get response from server but in my api , I need to send header along with it to get response from server , Which I am unable to do.So If I get the data using http.get then use that JSON in fake api using call in jsonp , so I think I will achieve , my desired result.

Comment: @ManishVashisth anticipating the header for CORS ? Or any another Header?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, yes i am using header values, but for jsonp , its doesn't take header, thats why i need help?

Comment: @ManishVashisth CORS headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *,  Access-Control-Request-Method: get post ...` are setting on back-end

Comment: @ManishVashisth you can not to affect from js

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick, i am able to get data using http.get with including httpHeader , but I am unable to use this api using http.jsonp . as they have used in this example : https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/external-editing/ . thanks for replying

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick . 
private fetch(action: string = '', data?: any): Observable<any[]> {
        return this.http
            .jsonp(`https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products/${action}?${this.serializeModels(data)}`, 'callback')
            .pipe(map(res => <any[]>res));
    }
there api. but if i use my api. then not working

Comment: @ManishVashisth jsonp has second param RequestOptionsArgs. RequestOptionsArgs has header field into itself. It means `options = {  headers: headers }`. Headers is class. `headers = new Header()`. headers has method append. headers.append('Content-Type', 'Application/json')

Comment: you can create `const headers = new Headers()` append your headers `headers.append('HEADER', 'VALUE')`and add this in `const options = { headers: headers}` and send jsonp.  `this.http.jsonp(URL, options)`

Comment: @ManishVashisth You are trying example which has deprecated code. Try this: https://angular.io/api/http/Jsonp. `jsonp` is deprecated and Angular suggests using `HttpClient`.

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick , I am getting errors. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m1cze2

Comment: @MaihanNijat, I am using HttpClient it self , Can you please help me, where am i going wrong?  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m1cze2

Comment: @ManishVashisth I watch http error. 404of ajax